# Is conditional expectation continuous in conditioning argument?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, least-squares, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose $X,Y$ are real-valued random vectors. When can we say $E[g(X,Y)|X]$ is an a.e. continuous function in $X$? I ask because I am reading Chapter 7 of [Hansen](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ebhansen/econometrics/Econometrics.pdf), which asserts without proof that the finite-sample conditional variance of the OLS estimator converges in probability to the asymptotic variance of the OLS estimator (p.167).  I have mostly convinced myself of this argument, save for one step where I want to argue
$E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}X_{i}'e_{i}^{2}|(X_1,...,X_n)'\right]\overset{p}{\rightarrow}E\left[E\left[X_{i}X_{i}'e_{i}^{2}\right]|(X_1,...,X_n)'\right]=E\left[X_{i}X_{i}'e_{i}^{2}\right]$
by appealing to the weak law of large numbers and the continuous mapping theorem.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896209/conditional-expectation-continuous-in-the-conditioning-argument) seems to suggest "near continuity," but not sure what precisely that means or if that would suffice here. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The error is $e_i=Y_i-X_i'\beta$ and model assumptions include $(X_i,Y_i)$ iid and finite fourth moments of $X_i,Y_i$. Then the claim can be shown without appealing to the continuous mapping theorem since

$$E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}X_{i}'e_{i}^{2}|(X_1,...,X_n)'\right]=
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}X_{i}'E\left[e_{i}^{2}|(X_1,...,X_n)'\right]\\
=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}X_{i}'E\left[e_{i}^{2}|X_i\right]\quad ((X_i,Y_i) \text{ iid})\\
\overset{p}{\rightarrow}E\left[X_{i}X_{i}'E\left[e_{i}^{2}|X_i\right]\right]\quad (\text{WLLN})\\
=E\left[E\left[X_{i}X_{i}'e_{i}^{2}|X_i\right]\right]\\=
E\left[X_{i}X_{i}'e_{i}^{2}\right]\quad (\text{LIE})$$

Comment: Your application of the WLLN is quite suspicious, since you still have a term with $n$ after taking limits

Comment: @JoseAvilez Thanks, it's a fair point. One of the assumptions of the linear regression model is $(X_i,Y_i)$ iid. Given $e_i=Y_i-X_i'\beta$, then we can write $E[e_i^2|(X_1,...,X_n)']=E[e_i^2|X_i]$ and then apply WLLN. This should redeem the argument then, no?

Comment: That doesn't seem correct to me. WLLN would require that $E(e_i^2 | X_i)$ be independent for $1\leq i \leq n$, which is not the case if by $e_i$ you mean the model residuals, rather than the errors (e.g. sum of residuals = 0).

Comment: $e_i$ is the *error* here (it's defined based on $\beta$, not $\hat\beta$). And then $E[e_i^2|X_i]$ will just be a function of $X_i.$

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, if you have independent errors, I think should be able to apply $WLLN$ to the mean of the sequence given by $X_i X_i^T E(e_i^2 | X_i)$ with no problem

Comment: Yep errors are indep since $(X_i,Y_i)$ iid. thanks for the input